GCPにてVPN接続する際の構成確認依頼
複数拠点にIPアドレスを持てるカードリーダーがあり、それらをGCP上に立てたサーバーで統合管理したいです。
各拠点にはグローバル固定IPアドレスを持たせたSIMルータがあります。GCPと各SIMルータでVPNを組むのは費用的に大きくなるため一度本社のVPN構築用ルータとSIMルータでVPNを組み本社のgatewayとGCPでトンネルを構築する予定です。この場合GCPで必要なものは添付しましたリンク内の構成で合ってますでしょうか。GCPからの下りは１カ月500GBの想定です。
Google Cloud 料金計算ツール: 計算結果

